# Transfer file from local machine to port forwarded machine

Tags: networking, router, terminal, scp, amazon-ec2

I have to transfer a file from my local machine to remote server 2 from remote server 1.

I have port forwarded the remote server1(Amazon Ec2) port 2222 to remote server2(Amazon Ec2). I am connecting that machine from my local by following command,

> ssh -i server.pem ec2-user@IP -p 2222

I am trying to transfer file using scp, however I am not able to find the perfect solution. Please help me on this.

**Note: Remote server 1 will act as a router.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scp uses uppercase P for the port option:

```
scp -i server.pem -P 2222 source-file ec2-user@IP:path/dest
```

Or did that gave an error?  Which one?